Create new mesh from a 3D Voronoi mesh according to a selection of sites
I am trying to implement a 3D version of ApproximateGeneralizedVoronoiMesh ; failing to understand the source code well enough, I wish to come up with a dirty and quick solution myself. The MWE I'm starting with is
c1[t_] := {-1, t, t};
c2[s_] := {1, -s, s};

pts1 = Table[c1[t], {t, -2, 2, 0.1}]; 
pts2 = Table[c2[s], {s, -2, 2, 0.1}]; 

vor = VoronoiMesh[Join[pts1, pts2], {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];
Show[Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], vor}}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, 
   Point@Select[MeshCoordinates[vor], 
     RegionMember[
      Cuboid[{-1.99, -1.99, -1.99}, {1.99, 1.99, 1.99}]]]}]]

Drawing from this post, the region occupied by the curve $c_1$ should be the union of the cells
cells1 = Pick[#, Or @@ RegionMember[#][pts1]] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vor, 3];

However, directly using RegionUnion has very underwhelming results, as the polyhedrons share a lot of there surface area.
The end goal would be to get a mesh representation of the separating surface, but getting a representation of the $c_1$ region is good enough for me. I see two potential types of results:

a mesh consisting of the cells occupied by the $c_1$ samples, along with the corrsponding edges, facets and vertices;
a single joined polyhedron built from the list cells1.

But for now I don't have a clear idea of how to proceed. I think the important step would be to come up with a combinePolyhedron helper function, im parallel to this one from the afore mentioned resource function:
combinePolygons[listOfPolygons_] := listOfPolygons //. {
    (* Merge polygons sharing an edge, 
    multiple cases to handle polygon rotations *)
    {a___, Polygon[{d___, x_, y_, e___}], b___, 
      Polygon[{f___, y_, x_, g___}], c___} -> {a, b, c, 
      Polygon[{d, x, g, f, y, e}]},
    {a___, Polygon[{d___, x_, y_, e___}], b___, 
      Polygon[{x_, f___, y_}], c___} -> {a, b, c, 
      Polygon[{d, x, f, y, e}]},
    {a___, Polygon[{y_, d___, x_}], b___, 
      Polygon[{f___, y_, x_, g___}], c___} -> {a, b, c, 
      Polygon[{f, y, d, x, g}]},
    {a___, Polygon[{y_, d___, x_}], b___, Polygon[{x_, f___, y_}], 
      c___} -> {a, b, c, Polygon[{x, f, y, d}]},
    (* Simplify polygons that contain overlapping edges, 
    such cases might arise due to merge transformations *)
    Polygon[{a___, x_, y_, x_, b___}] -> Polygon[{a, x, b}],
    Polygon[{y_, x_, a___, x_}] -> Polygon[{x, a}],
    Polygon[{x_, a___, x_, y_}] -> Polygon[{x, a}]
    };

Update:
For 1 I've found that I can simply do
polyhedrons = 
  Pick[#, AnyTrue[pts1, 
      RegionMember@
       First@MeshPrimitives[vor, MeshCellIndex[vor, #]]]] & /@ 
   MeshCells[vor, 3];
region1 = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[vor], polyhedrons]

Note that MeshCells only stores vertex indices and not coordinates, making the information in polyhedrons different from cells1. I took way too longer than I should have to understand this.
The next step of interest could be to properly implement a function that takes in several groups of sets (e.g., each a sample of a curve) and spits out a MeshRegion as the existing resource function does. I'm however also interested in another thing to do, namely to get the 3D-embedded 2D-mesh of the separating surface.

Related posts I've gone through:

Unify Polyhedrons into a single Polyhedron


Do forgive me if the question has a somewhat X-Y feeling to it, please. I don't have a clear idea whether I should output a polyhedron, a region, a meshregion, an elementmesh or something else yet, and I hope someone could give me suggestions.

The messages of the undocumentated Region`Mesh`MeshMembertCellIndex hints that it should work for 3-d embedded meshes, but has always crashed the kernel when I tried it. I also don't have a clue why that is.

I've honestly made this post into something more of an experiment journal. Hope someone may tell me how to moderate this to better abide to community rules...

My current attempt is contained in this notebook
